# Adding a UIGesture to a button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I created a number of buttons in IB and linked them to actions successfully. But I would like to have another action occur if the button is pinched. There is probably something basic that I have missed but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to add the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the button.

Answer (score 0):

i dont u can add a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the button normally we will add it into the View right. i think for UIButton the actions available just like "TouchUpInside" as defined in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can add a gesture to a `UIButton`.

Here is a small piece of code to give you a general idea:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:)];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
```

I don't think you have to do the whole `initWithTarget:self action:...` but this is the only way I have successfully done visual changes that are caused by `UIGestures` of some type.

If your following my example: `@selector(someAction:)];` you will declare the method like this:

```
-(void)someAction:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     //do what ever changes you want the gesture to cause here.
     //e.g. change the button size, color, shape
}
```